# how can I get latest of two dates in SQL case statement?

Tags: sql, hadoop, presto

I have a SQL table and need to check for the latest of two dates, creating a new column. There may or may not be both values, in which case it defaults to the one.

I have a production case like this:

```
+----------+----------+-----------+
|  device  | activity |   date    |
+----------+----------+-----------+
| device 1 | stage    | 3/20/2018 |
| device 1 | test     | 3/30/2018 |
| device 2 | stage    | 6/1/2018  |
| device 2 | test     | [null]    |
+----------+----------+-----------+
```

And I need to get this:

```
+----------+-----------------+
|  device  | stage_test_date |
+----------+-----------------+
| device 1 | 3/30/2018       |
| device 2 | 6/1/2018        |
+----------+-----------------+
```

I'm trying like this:

```
case 
    when activity in ('stage', 'test') 
    then (select max(date))
    else null
    end as stage_test_date,
```

but I get "Given correlated subquery is not supported" error. This is PrestoDB, which uses ANSI SQL. It works for "then (select date)" but that doesn't give me the greatest of the two dates.

Much appreciate your advice!

Answer (score 1):

Why not just do this?

```
select device, max(date)
from t
group by device;
```

Or add a `where` if you want to limit the activities:

```
select device, max(date)
from t
where activity in ('stage', 'test') 
group by device;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use correlated `subquery` approach :

```
select t.*
from table t
where activity in ('stage', 'test') and
      date = (select max(t1.date) from table t1 where t1.device = t.device);
```

You can also use `GROUP BY` Clause :

```
select device, max(date) as stage_test_date
from table t
where activity in ('stage', 'test')
group by device;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use analytic max() in a subquery:

```
select
    case 
        when activity in ('stage', 'test') 
        then max_date 
    end as stage_test_date,
    ...
from
(
select t.*, 
       max(date) over () as max_date 
 from table t
) s
;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this

```
select device, max(date) as stage_test_date 
from production 
group by device
order by device asc
```